# Merging first element in sublist with elements in the same list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list below. I need to use it to create a new nested list with only the first element in the sublist with the last element in list.

```
a=[[a,b,c],3]
```

the outcome should look like

```
b=[[a,3],[b,3],[c,3]]
```

Comment: Should `a=[[a,b,c],3]` be `a=[['a','b','c'],3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()`:

```
In [79]: a=[['a','b','c'],3]

In [80]: list(zip(a[0], [a[1]]*len(a[0])))
Out[80]: [('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

Or:

```
In [83]: (a, b, c), num = a

In [84]: [(a, num), (b, num), (c, num)]
Out[84]: [('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

Or more general:

```
In [85]: lst, num = a

In [86]: from itertools import repeat

In [87]: list(zip(lst, repeat(num, len(lst))))
Out[87]: [('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

Another way is using a nested list comprehension:

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]]

In [16]: [(j, i) for i in a[1] for j in a[0]]
Out[16]: [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, thanks a lot, but do i have to do some changes if a =[['a','b','c'],[1,2]] and the output looks like a=[('a',1),('b',1),('c',1),('a',2),('b',2),('c',2)]

Comment: If the order is not important you can simply use `itertools.product`. `list(product(*a))`. Or check the update.

Comment: WELL, Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot, i appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [['a','b','c'], 3]
>>> sublist, value = a
>>> [[x, value] for x in sublist]
[['a', 3], ['b', 3], ['c', 3]]
```